# Weblogic Admin console not starting after restarting the servers

Tags: weblogic, weblogic8.x

I restarted the servers and performed a hard resetbut after that my web logic console stopped working.It wasn't starting. what could be the issue ? How to start web logic console ? WHere can I get the Error logs which can tell me why is the web logic console not starting ?

Comment: 1. Check if your Admin Server is up and running in stdout logs
2. If running then check on what IP and port it's listening to and try to access the console.
Your server stdout/stderr logs can give some clue